# How should all the GTA IV spin-offs, re-releases and 'complete editions' be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-rename-request, retag-request

With the upcoming (re)release of Grand Theft Auto IV Complete Edition for PC on March 19, 2020, there will be 5 different releases for GTA IV and their side stories:

- GTA IV

  - Standalone Game
  - PS3, Xbox 360 and PC (Games for Windows Live Disc and Steam Download)
- GTA IV The Lost and Damned

  - DLC
  - Xbox 360 and PC (Games for Windows Live Marketplace)
- GTA IV The Ballad of Gay Tony

  - DLC
  - Xbox 360 and PC (Games for Windows Live Marketplace)
- GTA IV Episodes from Liberty City

  - Compilation of TLAD and TBoGT
  - PS3, Xbox 360 and PC (Games for Windows Live Disc and Steam Download)
- GTA IV The Complete Edition

  - Compilation of IV, TLAD and TBoGT
  - PS3 and Xbox 360
- GTA IV Complete Edition

  - Compilation of IV, TLAD and TBoGT
  - PC (RGL and Steam) ([not yet released](https://steamcommunity.com/ogg/12210/announcements/detail/3176663794401897532))

As someone that has GTA IV and EFLC in PS3 Discs, PC Discs and Steam, I sometimes use one version over the other due to performance or bugs. This makes me raise some questions about how I should tag the questions.

The best that I can think of is:

- [grand-theft-auto-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4) for questions about the story, content, and features that are only available on Grand Theft Auto IV
- [grand-theft-auto-4-lost-and-damned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4-lost-and-damned) for questions about the story, content, and features that are only available on The Lost and Damned ([tlad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tlad) as a synonym)
- [grand-theft-auto-4-ballad-of-gay-tony](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4-ballad-of-gay-tony) for questions about the story, content, and features that are only available on The Ballad of Gay Tony ([tbogt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tbogt) as a synonym)
- [grand-theft-auto-4-eflc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4-eflc) and [grand-theft-auto-4-complete](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4-complete) for exclusive features of Episodes from Liberty City and The Complete Edition + Complete Edition respectively or technical support for them (ideally, with a platform tag like PC, Xbox 360, Xbox One or PS3)

(If the answer is yes for the TLAD and TBoGT tags, I can help with the retag of those)